Как заставить работать pywhatkit в docker
У меня есть питон проект который работает в контейнере docker. Как я могу использовать библиотеку pywhatkit(или похожую для отправки сообщение в whatsapp без применения платного api).pywhatkit открывает whatsapp web и отправляет сообщение в определенный чат. Если просто запустить проект с pywhatkit то будет ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    # import pywhatkit
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/pywhatkit/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pywhatkit.whats import (
  File "/app/pywhatkit/whats.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pyautogui as pg
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
                       ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen os>", line 679, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'

Как я понял это потому что библиотека не может увидеть экран но оно и понятно.
Файл docker:
FROM python:3.11-bookworm
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python","-u", "main.py"]


нашел вот такой вариант: https://github.com/open-wa/wa-automate-docker

нашел вот такой вариант: github.com/open-wa/wa-automate-docker отлично работает можно даже сделать бота в вотсапе с помощью него

Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.

Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — из очереди проверок
